# Xdotools alternative in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Focus an external window (shell) using JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584649/focus-an-external-window-shell-using-jna)

I'm looking for a realistic alternative to xdotools:
http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Xdotools works great but I would like to put in my java code some functions to simulate keyboard and mouse inputs in an ubuntu xterm. Is there a library to do that?

Note: My xterms are redirected with x11 redirection from an Aix OS to my Ubuntu OS. (My java server is on the Ubuntu side).