# Focus an external window (shell) using JNA

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I want to get the focus on a xterm using JNA (or JNI) knowing the xterm title. At the moment I'm doing it with xdotools but I want to change to pure Java. Is it possible? And how?

Note: I'm using ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Thank you for the question (+1). I did not know about xdotools. Please excuse my question but why do you want to do this? xdotools uses native API, so using it you are just saving your time.

Comment: I have a problem to get the returned string when executing something like:
exec("xdotool windowactivate xxx");
exec("xdotool type ls -a");
exec("xdotool key \"Return\"");
For the last line I can't get the result string of the ls -a...

Comment: Why don't you invoke "ls -a" directly with Runtime.exec() and read from the process output stream?

Comment: One of my xterm is already launched and is in fact a redirected DISPLAY from another platform. I need to write input in there and the only one solution I found is xdotool or java Robot class. Java Robot class need a focus window method that I couldnt find.

Comment: The http://abbot.sf.net project provides a library on top of robot (including a focus method), but fundamentally you need to move the mouse to where the window is and then click.  This handles both click-to-focus and focus-follows-mouse modes, provided the window is unobscured.

Comment: You should make note in your question that you're using the xterm as a method of executing commands on a remote host.  In general there are better solutions for performing such a task.